# localization works in preview but not in simulator/device

Tags: swift, localization

I work with 3 languages, on each of my storyboards, Xcode 8 created my storyboardName.strings (language) files and i changed all the strings to the correct languages inside the double quote.  I also have my localizable.strings files created for when i programatically need to change labels / alert messages.

Everything done programatically works fine on the simulator / device

The stroryboard labels/button doesn't translate on the simulator / device but  work when i do the preview side by side and change the language

Comment: Did you create the localizations manually?  I always export the xliff files, send them to the translator and reimport them.  It then works correctly on the simulator.

Comment: @JoshHomann thanks !!!!! yes i was manually changing the files.  Import/Export of the xliff file worked.